# Working with Lists and Parallel.Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I'm attempting to run methods using Parallel.Invoke, with each method appending the response to a list outside of Parallel.Invoke

I've been playing around using a lock, but the following code doesn't work

```
var allResults = new List<ResultRecord>();
var sync = new object();

Parallel.Invoke(
    () => { var results = GetResultSet1(); lock (sync) { allResults.Concat(results); } },
    () => { var results = GetResultSet2(); lock (sync) { allResults.Concat(results); } });
```

This code doesn't setup the list, allResults ends up being empty.

Comment: You are not saving value from `Concat` call. Possibly, you mean to use `AddRange`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Before setting up the Parallel.Invoke, I was using a string of concats that was working as expected

Answer (score 0):

As already explained by PetSerAl in a comment, `Concat()` does not modify the list, it *returns* the modified list. Using `AddRange()` instead of `Concat()` is a solution, but I think using `Task`s is clearer than `Parallel.Invoke()` here:

```
var resultSet1Task = Task.Run(() => GetResultSet1());
var resultSet2Task = Task.Run(() => GetResultSet2());

List<ResultRecord> allResults = resultSet1Task.Result.Concat(resultSet2Task.Result).ToList();
```

This way, there is no need for explicit locking, which makes the code safer.

If you can, you could also use `await` instead of `.Result`.